# Is Jersey Rest Client more optimal than HttpClient for calling a restful service?

Tags: json, rest, jakarta-ee, jersey, gson

I am need to call the a resful api that will return json response.  I am thinking about using jersey client api but not sure if it is in any way better than just using HttpClient directly and then using GSON to convert the response to Java objects.

Answer (score 11):

Jersey client is *far* better than HttpClient from a coding efficiency standpoint. Consider:

```
// Jersey client
WebResource resource = Client.create().resource("http://foo.com")
resource.path("widgets").entity(someWidget).type(APPLICATION_JSON).post();
Wodget wodget = resource.path("widgets/wodget").accept(APPLICATION_XML).get(Wodget.class);
```

as opposed to:

```
// HttpClient
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://foo.com/widgets");
HttpEntity someWidgetEntity = ... // something with GSON to marshal the 'someWidget'
httpPost.setEntity(someWidgetEntity);
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://foo.com/widgets/wodget");
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
if (entity != null) {
    ... // something with GSON to read in the wodget
}
```

Add in the fact that the Jersey client can use HttpClient under the covers for its HTTP interaction, and you get the best of both worlds: a simplified interface plus the power of a widely-used and versatile HTTP client library.

Note: Above code is completely untested but roughly accurate in shape.

Comment: The code might look simpler but I'm still not convinced.  The number of lines of code is only one factor

Comment: You asked if the Jersey client "is in any way better" than HttpClient. I'm pointing out one of its huge strengths. If you have additional concerns, make your question more specific. I'll also add that 1) I've been using Jersey--both server and client--for about 3 years now, 2) I have some experience with HttpClient as well, and 3) I will unreservedly recommend the Jersey client over using HttpClient directly.

Comment: If you have been using it for that long, you should be able to quickly list several advantages/disadvantages of the technology.

Comment: I've already answered the question you asked. What other aspects are you interested in if "ease of use" isn't enough?

Comment: resource.path("widgets").entity(someWidget) can this ever be null?

Comment: The value returned by `.entity(someWidget)`? No, it'll never be null. If you mean can `someWidget` be null, then I suppose you could pass null to `.entity()`, but I don't know why you'd want to. It doesn't make sense to do so.

Comment: Efficiency in execution, of course. Is probably far more important.

Answer (score 1):

Its not like that which one is better, they have their own pros and cons, like Jersey client is in fact pretty straightforward in terms of number of lines of codes that are require to do lets say any HTTP action. But predominantly HttpClient gives you lots of control over your actions, Just to explain you; if there's Jersey Client code for Http POST Multipart feature if multiple threads are called to hit this service, Jersey client fails intermittently with Socket closed Exception, whereas HttpClient performs flawless and that's because HttpCLient internally does retry whereas in Jersey Client doesn't do that.